# Are questions about pornographic material allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272002/looking-for-id-of-softcore-sci-fi-porn-movie-on-cinemax-or-showtime-or-something) question on review tasks.

So are such type of questions allowed on the site? I mean technically the OP does say that it has sci-fi elements such as the presence of a cyborg and aliens but then again there exist hardcore porn parodies of major sci-fi franchises.

So anybody could ask questions about such movies and get away with it.

So are such questions on topic here?

Answer (score 4):

For a story-id question I believe we *can't*, by precedent, rule it off-topic.  While whether or not a particular work is on-topic or not largely comes down to cases, one of the unique things about story-id questions is that we don't *know* the applicable work.  In general we are very lenient with story-id questions as long as the asker makes a good-faith assertion that they believe the work is on-topic and can point to at least some SFnal trope or detail.

Also, there are obviously a number of *written* SF works that are quite sexually graphic, some beyond even what would be possible to film.  (I'm not recommending reading it, quite the contrary, but if you've read Farmer's *Image of the Beast* you know what I'm talking about.)  These are obviously on-topic, especially those where the space-phlebotinum requires sex to work.  If someone were to film those works, they would likely be pornographic, but still definitely on-topic.

Even beyond that, consider that the genre includes works that are basically serial-numbers-filed-off westerns transposed into a "space" milieu.  Wooden ships and iron men *in space* is also an accepted part of the genre, along with space-pirates...
I don't think we can be less accommodating of SFnal transformations of any other base style.  In other words if a space-western is on-topic, then space-porn pretty much has to be too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why they shouldn't be, as long as they are on topic by being sf or fantasy.

We do need to make sure to keep [the minimum age as specified in the TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#age) in mind when writing posts, but while the *subject* of a post may be adult material, there's no need to describe it using such explicit terms that it's not appropriate for minors.

That even goes for porn parodies of sf/f works, as long the parodies are sufficiently sf/f-nal themselves and the questions are sufficiently about the sf/f-nal aspects.

Also note that while your example is explicitly asking for identification of a soft porn movie, a lot of books that are considered on topic contain material of a similar level of explicitness.

Comment: the point is as i mentioned that there exist adult parodies of  major scifi franchises, and such movies obviously are low budget and pay zero attention to detail, so now consider someone asks why a character did what they did in the parody movie then the question would be unanswerable since such movies dont have a generic plot and sense and exist for one reason only which is you know ..........

Comment: As long as the questions are about the sf/f-nal elements, sure. I'll update my answer to reflect that.